# parse text file using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am looking to parse a space delimited input text file using awk.
The column code can have more than one row for each group. 
I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

```
LOCATION
SHANNON

GROUP  NUM  SWITCH  CODE HEX
0      4     OFF    1    3
1      13    ON     2    4      
                    8
                    14

LOCATION
LOUTH

GROUP  NUM  SWITCH  CODE HEX 
0      1    OFF     1    4
1      2    ON      0    F
                    2
```

Desired output file

```
LOCATION GROUP  NUM  SWITCH  CODE HEX
SHANNON   0     4    OFF     1    3
SHANNON   1     13   ON      2    4  
SHANNON   1     13   ON      8    4  
SHANNON   1     13   ON      14   4 
LOUTH     0     1    OFF     1    4
LOUTH     1     2    ON      0    F
LOUTH     1     2    ON      2    F
```

Comment: why does it have to be awk?

Comment: awk seems to be very quick and does not use any other programs

Comment: I was using vba for parsing, in comparison awk is much quicker in performing similar operations. Do you have any other way to suggest?

Comment: Awk is powerful but has limits though and when it tries to comprehend for its limits, that would be the point where it becomes slow or code bulky.

Comment: @SantoshPillai When other variables are not present, it's only the code that code exist right?

Comment: Yes, only values for code exist when other variables are not there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # You can customize this to change your output layout based on your preference.
    format = "%-10s%-7s%-5s%-8s%-5s%-3s\n"
    printf format, "LOCATION", "GROUP", "NUM", "SWITCH", "CODE", "HEX"
}
++i==2{
    l = $1
}
i>4{
    if (/^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
        i = 0
    } else if (NF > 1) {
        printf format, l, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
        p1=$1; p2=$2; p3=$3; p5=$5
    } else {

        printf format, l, p1, p2, p3, $1, p5
    }
}
```

Run with:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Output:

```
LOCATION  GROUP  NUM  SWITCH  CODE HEX
SHANNON   0      4    OFF     1    3  
SHANNON   1      13   ON      2    4  
SHANNON   1      13   ON      8    4  
SHANNON   1      13   ON      14   4  
LOUTH     0      1    OFF     1    4  
LOUTH     1      2    ON      0    F  
LOUTH     1      2    ON      2    F
```

Comment: @SantoshPillai Please check.

Comment: Works great. Perfect :)